# 400 Bad Request with Traefik v2 and NextcloudPi

Tags: docker, http, https, docker-compose, traefik

I try to run my NextcloudPi-Docker installation behind Traefik to allow for more services on the server and ensure a simple SSL encryption for all of them.

My `docker-compose.yml` for Nextcloudpi without Traefik looked like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  nextcloud:
    image: ownyourbits/nextcloudpi-armhf
    container_name: nextcloud
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /media/external_1/nextcloud:/data
      - /media/external_1/backup:/backup
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

That works fine, my existing installation is starting smoothly.

When I start `Traefik` with its `docker-compose.yml` I can open the dashboard, no problem. I also tried `Portainer`, as a route of `Traefik`, that works, but I don't want to make it more complex, so I stay with the text based config.

Traefik's `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./logs:/logging
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`sub.domain.tld`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=<user>:<password>
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`sub.domain.tld`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

NextcloudPi `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  nextcloud:
    image: ownyourbits/nextcloudpi-armhf
    container_name: nextcloud
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /media/external_1/nextcloud:/data
      - /media/external_1/backup:/backup
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.rule=Host(`sub.domain.tld`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.middlewares=nextcloud-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.rule=Host(`sub.domain.tld`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nextcloud-secure.service=nextcloud"
      - "traefik.http.services.nextcloud.loadbalancer.server.port=443"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

The output of the `access.log` is as following:

```
151.177.45.100 - - [07/Mar/2020:15:20:44 +0000] "GET /status.php HTTP/1.1" 400 362 "-" "-" 22 "nextcloud-secure@docker" "http://172.19.0.4:443" 5ms
151.177.45.100 - - [07/Mar/2020:15:21:16 +0000] "GET /status.php HTTP/1.1" 400 362 "-" "-" 23 "nextcloud-secure@docker" "http://172.19.0.4:443" 3ms
151.177.45.100 - - [07/Mar/2020:15:21:48 +0000] "GET /status.php HTTP/1.1" 400 362 "-" "-" 24 "nextcloud-secure@docker" "http://172.19.0.4:443" 9ms
151.177.45.100 - - [07/Mar/2020:15:22:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 400 362 "-" "-" 25 "nextcloud-secure@docker" "http://172.19.0.4:443" 8ms
```

And the `traefik.yml`:

```yaml
api:
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false

certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: email@address.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
log:
  filePath: "/logging/traefik.log"
  format: json
  level: DEBUG

# Configuring a buffer of 100 lines
accessLog:
  filePath: "/logging/access.log"
  bufferingSize: 100
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, I use the same domain as without Traefik and as I said, other services work great with it. I even tried to create a fresh NextcloudPi instance, but that didn't work either.
I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: can you add the ./data/traefik.yml ?

Comment: I added the content of the traefik.yml now.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, I can say that the root cause of this issue is one of the following

1- `nextcloud`  service is not listening to the port `443` and that is why you get the `400` error. you need to modify this line to fix it

```
   - "traefik.http.services.nextcloud.loadbalancer.server.port=443"
```

2- the requests and not served by nextcloud and that is because you are using the same rule (hostname) to manage different services

```
- "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`sub.domain.tld`)"
```

check this [post](https://medium.com/better-programming/traefik-2-1-as-a-reverse-proxy-c9e274da0a32) for more info

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
1 - Does that mean that I can't have the loadbalancer on port `443` or should I just delete the line completely? I don't think that I actually need it for my purposes, but I found it in almost all tutorials online.
2 - I see, should I use different hostnames? Wouldn't that be counterintuitive? Or use `Port` instead of `Host` as a rule determinator?

Comment: 1- You need that line if you planning to use the hostname (you just need to use the correct port). 2. yes, you need to use subdomains if you want to get the best of traefik.  This post explains it step by step. https://medium.com/better-programming/traefik-2-1-as-a-reverse-proxy-c9e274da0a32

Comment: Ok, I see. Or better I don't really see it... 
1- What is the correct port? I want to access `nextcloud` which is a apache webserver that wants `443`, port `80` doesn't work. Do you know which port I need?
2- I actually use different subdomains even different DynDNS-providers for `traefik` and `nextcloud`. Do I need a special subdomain for the SSL-connection to `nextcloud`? 
The questions might sound stupid, but I couldn't find the solution in the tutorial you sent me (but it's saved for my next adventure - docker swarms) ;-)